# how to share photos in wordpress on the single page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slider

if I have two sliders on the page, how to make one group of images be on the first slider and the second group of pages be on the second slider.When I do they are getting mixed. I think I need to add some type of class but I do not know where. Can it be done in this piece of code or is it made in the WordPress admin panel?

```php-template
<section class="up-slider">
    <div class="up-slider__inner">
        
    <?php
    global $post;

    $myposts = get_posts([ 
        'numberposts' => -1,
    ]);

    if( $myposts ){
        foreach( $myposts as $post ){
            setup_postdata( $post );
            ?>
            <?php  bloginfo('template_url');  ?>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail();  ?>
            <?php 
        }
    } 

    wp_reset_postdata(); // Сбрасываем $post
    ?>
                  
    </div>
</section>
```